# Jboss shutdown abruptly while running application

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

I'm using JBOSS EAP version 7.3 and Eclipse Version: 2021-12 M1 (4.22.0 M1) with JDK 1.8.0. I'm able to deploy my services as a war and application fine until when I navigate to some steps in application, JBOSS shutdown with below error message.
This is happening on window machine

```
19:41:04,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0272: Suspending server
19:41:04,210 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
19:41:04,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
19:41:04,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = ABCDService.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_11_2
19:41:04,280 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = ABCDService.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
19:41:04,281 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = XYZService.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
19:41:04,283 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = XYZService.war
19:41:04,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = ABCDService.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
19:41:04,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = ABCDService.war
19:41:04,293 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/abcd]
19:41:04,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = XYZService.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
19:41:04,323 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
19:41:04,333 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/XYZService' from server 'default-server'
19:41:04,351 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/ABCDService' from server 'default-server'
19:41:04,371 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = MySqlJDBCDriver
19:41:04,372 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'ABCDService'
19:41:04,387 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
19:41:04,392 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:41:04,394 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:41:04,394 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:41:04,438 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:41:04,453 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 115) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:41:04,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 122) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
19:41:04,842 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
19:41:04,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
19:41:04,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
19:41:04,914 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
19:41:04,915 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
19:41:04,916 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8443
19:41:04,918 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
19:41:04,923 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001 stopping
19:41:05,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment XYZServices (runtime-name: XYZService.war) in 1602ms
19:41:05,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment ABCDService (runtime-name: ABCDService.war) in 1737ms
19:41:05,977 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0050: JBoss EAP 7.3.0.GA (WildFly Core 10.1.2.Final-redhat-00001) stopped in 1722ms
```

I tried looking at other threads on mysteries shutdown but no luck https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-11456 .

Comment: Note: M1 is a milestone release intended only for testing during release development. You should move to the final 2021-12 release.

Comment: Are you sure you did not do a kind of Ctrl+C (because the log says: "Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal")  ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco thank you!! yeah.. actually in the lib code ..I see system.exit()